# VLC does not play all songs

Tags: iphone, music, vlc

I copied a couple dozen MP3s to an iPhone through iTunes. To play them I used VLC however VLC does *not* play the next song. How do I have VLC play all the music on the device without having to constantly pick up the phone, turn the screen on and manually tell it to play the next song?

Answer (score 1):

There's a three dot menu in the bottom right hand corner of the screen when you are playing a file...

[image: menu showing arrows crossed out]

if you tap that the top item once and you'll get "repeat one" tap it again and you get "repeat all" which when I tried it, changed the behavior from quitting at the end of a track to playing the next track.

[image: repeat all icon]

It will also probably repeat the playlist when it gets to the end though.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes has a "shuffle" setting where it will play all tracks randomly or play all sequentially.

I don’t believe vlc has that, afaik...

Why not just use iTunes..

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem for me on Mac, too.

Even though I'm not on iPhone, this post came up when I searched for an answer, so I figured I'd share here what I learned since I bet it will help other people.

1. (top bar menu) VLC Media Player > Settings...
2. Interface > Show All
3. Choose "Playlist" in the left panel
4. Uncheck options like "Play and pause", which had been checked (true) on mine.

[image: settings]